# How to install Rcplex on Mac

Tags: r, cplex

I am trying to link R with the IBM Cplex studio but unable to do so.

First I installed the Cplex studio on my desktop. Next I directly tried installing the 'Rcplex package' in R but got a configuration error. "configure: error: CPLEX include directory ./include does not exist:"
Next I researched a bit to find the solution and found out that the Rcplex package requires the CPLEX include directory. I then tried to add arguments in the installation through Terminal but no success.

Source : https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/web/packages/Rcplex/INSTALL

`R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="PKG_CFLAGS='-m64 -fPIC' PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/include PKG_LIBS='-L/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -m64 -lm -lpthread -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit'" Rcplex_0.3-0.tar`

Error message received : "Warning: invalid package ‘Rcplex_0.3-0.tar’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified"

Comment: A question that is nearly identical was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710379

Comment: There are a number of ways to install as shown in the INSTALL file. Have you tried all of them? Can you edit your question to show all of the screen output starting with your command line? And just to be sure, what do you see if you do `ls /Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/`?