# Errors while installing Rcplex in R on MAC

Tags: r, cplex

I am trying to install Rcplex on MAC but I am running into very strange error. I ran the following command on terminal:

R CMD INSTALL --configure-args=" \
--with-cplex-lib='/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/' \
--with-cplex-include='/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/include/' \
--with-cplex-link='-lcplex -m64 -lm -pthread' \
--with-cplex-check='/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/examples/src/c' \
--with-cplex-cflags='-m64 -fPIC'" \
Rcplex

and got the following error:
checking for library containing CPXversion... no
configure: error: Could not link CPLEX library using /Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rcplex’

Comment: There are a number of  ways to install as shown in the [INSTALL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/INSTALL) file. Have you tried all of them? Can you edit your question to show all of the screen output starting with your command line? And just to be sure, what do you see if you do `ls /Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/`?

Comment: A question that is nearly identical was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708929